# How to fix task bar auto showing on windows 11 - due to application 'needing attention'

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, hide

The problem I see (with taskbar auto hide on) is that the task bar shows for applications that 'need attention' - and then won't hide again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To autohide (once) from a 'flashed' application/s (i.e. needing attention), you have to navigate to the application window/s before the taskbar will autohide again.  You may also need to open/view any notifications as well.

If (like me) you find this tedious, then you can disable the flashing notifications (completely).  N.B. This also means you will no longer see the little red bar appear underneath an application when it needs attention:

- Right click the task bar >> Taskbar Settings, then choose `Taskbar behaviors`.
- Set/unset the following:

  - Set `Automatically hide the taskbar` (this should already be set)
  - Unset `Show flashing on taskbar apps` (this stops you knowing when an application needs attention)
  - (optional) Unset `Show badges on taskbar apps` (this stops notifications showing the taskbar - which can also be annoying...)

I hope this is useful ...